# Read and change multiple XML files in Excel (2007) VBA - additional

Tags: xml, parsing, vba

I have tried to use a code (mr. Olle Sjögren's answer on Aug 15 at 13:08) to replace one line with two lines in multiple xml files in folder d:\eBobo

For example, I would like to change one line (which is the same in all xml files in that folder):

aaaaaaaaaa

into lines (also in all xml files):

bbbbbbbbbb

cccccccccc

This is my attempt:

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Const sSearchString As String = "d:\eBobo\*.xml"

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFilePath As String


    sFileName = Dir(sSearchString)

    Do While sFileName <> ""

        sFilePath = "d:\eBobo\" & sFileName  'Get full path to file
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        sTemp = ""  'Clear sTemp

        Open sFilePath For Input As iFileNum

            Do Until EOF(iFileNum)

                Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
                sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf

            Loop

        Close iFileNum

        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "aaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbb" <br /> "cccccccccc")

        iFileNum = FreeFile

        Open sFilePath For Output As iFileNum
        Print #iFileNum, sTemp

        Close iFileNum

        sFileName = Dir() 'Get the next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

I get a message Syntax Error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this removing extra quotation marks:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "aaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbb <br /> cccccccccc")
```

If you actually want two lines in your xml code try this:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "aaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbb" & vbCRLF & "cccccccccc")
```

Comment: I have tried, but this just returns one line:                        bbbbbbbbbb <br /> cccccccc                                           Thanks Daniel

Comment: Gave you something else based upon your additional information.